# facing error as syntax error near unexpected token fi'

Tags: shell-script

```
#/bin/sh
file="C:/khushal/prop.txt"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
 while IFS= read -r key value
  do
    key=$(echo $key | tr '.' '_')
    eval ${key}=\${value}
     echo "User Id       = " ${db_uat_user}
      echo "user password = " ${db_uat_passwd}
 else
     echo "$file not found."
fi
```

Comment: Put it through https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I'd expect `else`  to be unexpected here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `done` token to match the `while ... do` statement.

it's often better to short-circuit the script by reversing the test on the file, which results in the if .. then .. else not spanning so many lines. I.e.:

```
#/bin/sh
file="C:/khushal/prop.txt"
if ! [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file not found."
    exit 1
fi
echo "$file found."
while IFS= read -r key value
do
   key=$(echo $key | tr '.' '_')
   eval ${key}=\${value}
   echo "User Id       = " ${db_uat_user}
   echo "user password = " ${db_uat_passwd}
done
```

Comment: `key` and `value` are being used unsanitized here. Also, use `printf` to output variable data, and double quote expansions.